# "At least one SSDL artifact is required for creating StoreItemCollection" Error with Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have recently been getting this error on my ASP.NET MVC project that uses the Entity Framework:

> At least one SSDL artifact is required for creating StoreItemCollection

The error occurs when I try to query the database in a controller action.  Has anyone seen this error before?  It only occurs every once in a while for me but I am looking for ways to resolve it.

EDIT: I am using Visual Studio 2008 SP1 so the version of Entity Framework should be version 1.  I have also tried regenerating the EDMX file which has not helped.

Comment: What version of EF are you using?  And what error code is showing?  The only google link similarity I could find was: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/fc58df2c-4f58-4d9f-bf09-6360c3994e1d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue was being caused by the pattern I was using with my ObjectContext.  I was using a Singleton, which just didn't apply well with the ASP.NET MVC framework.  I believe the ObjectContext was being disposed when I tried to use it again, hence the error.

I have moved to more of an 'ObjectContext Per Http Request' pattern, as described in [this blog post](http://cgeers.wordpress.com/2009/02/21/entity-framework-objectcontext/#aspnet).  So far, this has worked much better.

Answer (score 0):

Well, SSDL is part of your EDMX. It's recreated from scratch when you do an "Update Model from Database" in the GUI designer. So the first thing I'd do if I saw this is to connect to a DB with a known good schema and update model.