# Why does Entity give me an "SSDL fragment is required" statement with a remote DB, but not SQL Express?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090079/at-least-one-ssdl-artifact-is-required-for-creating-storeitemcollection-error), I am trying to run an Entity CodeFirst project.  I'm using the `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists` initializer.  I am a sysadmin on the box the connect string points to.

If I change (or remove) the connection string, Entity will create the database on my local SQLExpress instance.  Why won't it create the database on my remote instance?  *And, furthermore, why does it seem to require an artifact of data-first?*  This is a brand new project that is using nothing but code-first.

Using EF4.2.  Remote machine is SQL2k8.

Comment: It is not artifact of database first. It is core EF artifact and code first is crating it at runtime internally.